# No utm_campaign information in the play install referrer API?

Tags: android, google-ads-api

We're using google ads apps to download ads to promote apps. After the user opens the app by clicking on the advertisement installation, the install referrer information will be obtained through the play install referrer API and uploaded to our user log system. But there is no utm_campaign information in all the user's install referrer information uploaded now.

Here's information for some users' install referrers:

1. Users who install apps from ads in YouTube: pcampaignid=inline|youtubeads|9416164 (only this one parameter)
   2, from google play ads to install app users: gclid=CjwKCAiAg6yRBhBNEiwAeVyL0Bt1IRkH-LVH0n7FjV9ohyKeL9tEzwj9qWtL9pNExWSCHN94jBF0kBoC7kIQAvD_BwE (only this one parameter)
   3, there are some users: utm_source = google-play & utm_medium = organic (only these two parameters)
   4, there are some users: utm_source = (not_set) & utm_medium = (not_set) (only these two parameters)

Retrieved, none of the user's install referrer contains utm_campaign information.
Have you ever encountered this problem?